# Ruby: Defining methods dynamically based on variable values

Tags: ruby

I want to achieve something like below. Defining method names based on array arguments and Call them.

```
arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

arr.each { |role|
  # If the method already exists don't define new
  if ! method_exist? "init_#{role}"
    define "init_#{role}"
      p "I am method init_#{role}"
    end
}

init_beta
init_gamma
```

Edit:
If such a method already exists, don't define a new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as below :

```
arr = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']

arr.each do |role|
  # this code is defining all the methods at the top level. Thus call to 
  # `method_defined?` will check if any method named as the string argument 
  # is already defined in the top level already. If not, then define the method.
  unless self.class.private_method_defined?( "init_#{role}" )
    # this will define methods, if not exist as an instance methods on 
    # the top level.
    self.class.send(:define_method, "init_#{role}" ) do
      p "I am method init_#{role}"
    end
  end
end

init_beta # => "I am method init_beta"
init_gamma # => "I am method init_gamma"
```

Look at the documentation of [`private_method_defined`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-private_method_defined-3F) and [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

Note : I have used `private_method_defined?`, as on top level, all instance method you will be defining ( using `def` or `define_method` in the *default accessibility level* ), become as *private* instance methods of `Object`. Now as per your need you can also check [`protected_method_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-protected_method_defined-3F) and [`public_method_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-public_method_defined-3F) accordingly.

Comment: I am getting error "undefined method `method_defined?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)". Ruby version is 'ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]'